# Cannot get any flavor of Linux to install

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, system-installation

Machine is a Gateway Turion (single core 64 bit) with 2 GB RAM and 120 GB hard drive. I asked this in a previous question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444979/yet-another-install-question), but I now have another day of trying things so I can report/ask better questions, I hope.

Ubuntu, Mint and Lubuntu all lock at approximately 75-80% into the install. When I say lock, I mean the mouse dies, the cursor stops revolving and the keyboard is locked out.  A power off is all that will work. I tried both Live CD and Install on both 32 and 64-bit verified CDs. I found Hardware test when booted from the CD, ran that, and the primary tests for computer, disk and memory all passed. (no failures, but skipped unimportant tests)  I changed the BIOS settings to remove any auto magic like sleep, screen dimming or the like. From the CD, I can edit and save files to the hard drive, so I assume it is formatted/partitioned properly.  I turned off the Broadcom wireless, connected a network cable so it would have internet access (works fine), and tried to install again. Same issue.. 75-80% in, lockup. Tried Mint, lockup. Tried Lubuntu, lockup. All look suspiciously similar in their install programs.

*Is there a way to install the full install from terminal, or at least use a -verbose tag or the like so I can see what the install is hanging up on?* <-- Never answered

*I tried to create a bootable USB, and that also failed at 34%, but I had an idea of creating the bootable disk on the hard drive, which showed up in the utility.  Is this possible?* <-- Never Answered here, though found the answer

This is VERY frustrating. I was able to install and run FreeBSD with no issues, so there has to be some way to get the OS onto the hard drive!

Initial problem solved: see answer below.

Comment: I forgot to add in the above that I also tried using the whole HD in one partition and partitioning the HD into two 60GB drives.  Same-same. Lockup.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question, not to be snarky, but to let anyone else in the same boat know about the solution I found to this.  I have found TWO solutions:

Solution 1:
For those of you who may get a lock up in the graphical installer at 'Preparing to install', or try to install Mint or Lubuntu and get a lockup 75-80% in: this seemed to work for me.  Your mileage may vary!  After 5+ days of frustration trying to install Ubuntu, here is my solution.

I tried installing Ubuntu, Mint and Lubuntu, and the graphical installer always locked up.  The cursor quit spinning, the keyboard and mouse was locked out, and no matter how long you wait, it does not progress.  The only thing that worked was a power off.

The problem system:

Gateway MX6442 (MX6440 series) w/ Turion64 single core CPU
(previously a Windows XP Multimedia Edition computer)
2GB ram
120GB HD
Philips CD-DVD drive
Ethernet
Broadcom 4313 wireless card *******  One major issue is the wireless card!  ********

I finally downloaded the alternate CD at http://releases.ubuntu.com/ (THANKS @Marky) and tried that install.  I selected the language and other settings it asked for, then selected Install Ubuntu.  It got to 19% and locked up at 'retrieving nic-modules-3.11.0-15-generic-di' and a power off was all that would work.

To get past the hangup in the alternate disk installer, I turned the wireless off via the keyboard: FN+F2 on the Gateway.  The Broadcom wireless is a known issue in Ubuntu as you can see by searching the forums for Broadcom.  There should be a way to turn off the wireless through the keyboard for most computers.  Consult your user manual for the combo for your computer.  This worked to get past the problem lockup at 19% above.

*There SHOULD also be an option on the installer to skip/turn-off the wireless device to allow installation to continue, not just a totally locked system!*

So, the install got to 92%, 'retrieving file 16 of 20' and appeared to stop again since there was no [n sec remaining] message as with almost all other files that took a while to load.  However, after waiting a while it did complete loading and continued with the installation and successfully completed.

It ejected the CD and rebooted into Ubuntu!  Woo-Hoo!  After 5 days, I FINALLY get to see Linux on this machine!

Now I will need to go see about getting the wireless to work.  I will try the solution here:

[How to install Broadcom wireless drivers? (BCM43xx)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx)

Hopefully, the system will then be fully functional.  I will continue this after trying the above.

Since this was a brand new Ubuntu install, I did not need to remove anything in the system.  I followed the instructions in the above link, turned the wireless back on via keyboard before the last reboot command, and the wireless came up after the boot.  I was able to see and log in to my wireless router, and so far it has worked with no issues!

So, after 5+ days of total frustration, I FINALLY have an installed, fully functional Ubuntu installation!  I hope this helps someone else that has the same type of issues!

Solution 2:
After three days of trying to get ANY flavor of Linux to install on the Gateway laptop, I installed PC-BSD 10.0.  The first install failed, but at least it told me WHY it failed.  I restarted the install in VESA mode, and lo and behold, it installed first time.

Why did Linux fail?  It would seem there are three problem devices on this system: the video card (ATI), the sound card (???) and the wireless card (Broadcom).  The PC-BSD either correctly identified and loaded the correct drivers, or disabled them and continued.  In the end, everything works except the sound card, and it can run the same DE's as Ubuntu, Mint or Lubuntu.

Hopefully this answer will not get deleted, and will prove useful to those of you who just cannot get Linux to install.  I spent three frustrating days trying everything I could think of, and less than 4.5 hours (including a 3.6GB download) installing PC-BSD.

Thanks for all the suggestions.  I do appreciate those of you who actually tried to help. :)

Comment: I have been following your posts over the past days; good to see that you have a working system now, and compliments for your perseverance. If you are sure that the presence of the Broadcom wireless card actually breaks the installation procedure, you might consider reporting this as a bug on Launchpad.

Comment: Thanks @jos I am considerably less frustrated now.  I have already reported it as a bug, I hope.  I am not 100% sure that the Broadcom was the issue with all 3 graphical installers locking up, because I still got the lockup AFTER turning off the wireless device.  However, I am 99% sure it was what was causing the lockup at Preparing to Install on the Ubuntu install, since it also locked up the Alternative install.  At least you could see what was causing the issue (nic) with the Alternate install, which is why I turned it off via keyboard.  Then the install worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment, but I was guess I don't have enough reputation, so don't count this as an answer as I don't completely know what the cause of this is.

This is only a suggestion. Maybe you could try booting the CD into nomodeset? When it boots into this screen https://www.logicsupply.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/boot_splash.png (Lubuntu will automatically give you the option) then push the down arrow, select your language, then push f6 and click nomodeset. Then push escape and go to install Ubuntu. I had problems with my Laptop freezing on a black screen when trying to install Lubuntu and Ubuntu. For me it was a graphical error, and the nomodeset fixed it. It refreshes once installed and should work.

Comment back and let me know if this was of any help.

Comment: Sorry, totally misread your suggestion.  Too many tries at installs I guess.  I did find that after reparsing your reply, and tried it.  I almost immediately got an error on the install: Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error.  Details show /usr/bin/jockey-gtk and the install locked up on the preparing screen.

Comment: And then I found this: [link]http://www.rice86.com/blog/jockey-gtk-ubuntu-1204/

Comment: No change booting to nomodeset, other than now it hangs at preparing to install again. The typo wasn't it either.  I finally got a chance to look at the file, and the typo is fixed.  So once again, I am at a loss to explain why I cannot load Linux on this machine.  Hardware checks out (ran all tests this time), disk works, but 3 different install programs all stall at the same place.  Frustrating, since nobody seems to have any answers, especially the developers. *sigh*  I guess I am stuck with FreeBSD, since that loads perfectly.